# Private/Protected setters with F#

Tags: nhibernate, f#, functional-programming, c#-to-f#

I have decided to undertake a relatively large project with F# together with MVC4 and Nhibernate.

Now, in C#, my usual practice with ORM's is the have private setters for certain properties (E.g. auto-incremented/identity properties, timestamps, etc). I.e

```cs
public class Guide
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; private set; }

    public Guide()
    {
        Created = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Here id is an "identity column", and the ORM will handle setting its value.

In F# here is what I have so far

```
type public Guide() =
    member val public Id = 0 with get, set
    member val public Created = DateTime.MinValue with get, set
```

But the problem I have encountered is that the getters/setters cannot have access modifiers!

I am new with F#, so I would like to know the best way to perform this sort of thing. However, I do not just want to rewrite C# code in F#! I would like to know the correct (functional) approach to this. Maybe use some other construct??

Edit: For NHibernate, replace private with protected in the setters :)

Comment: Ah yes, the anonymous down-voters. Making their pointless presence felt as usual...

Comment: This may explain downvoter's presence: "Why oh why didn't I check on MSDN first." :)

Comment: A bit harsh to downvote me on that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Properties (F#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483467.aspx) page on MSDN, you *can* have access modifiers on your getters/setters. You can also use different access modifiers for the getter and setter (e.g., a public `get` and a private `set`).

What you *can't* do is use difference access modifiers for automatically-implemented properties. So, if you want to use different access modifiers you'll need to manually implement the backing field (with a `let`) and the getter/setter methods.

Comment: Do'h. Why oh why didn't I check on MSDN first. Thank you very much and apologies for my laziness!